# SwiftUI Passing Values to a view with Binding

Tags: view, swiftui

I have a block of code in my app that will be used many times for different values and on different CoreData entities. Basically it consists of a small header label and a `TextField` that becomes editable when the user taps on the edit button (which manages saving to the context).

I would like to be able to pass a label, an entity attribute (that stays connected to CoreData) and a state variable to it.

The block looks like this:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("Notes").font(.caption2).foregroundColor(.secondary)
    TextField("Notes", text: $todo.notes)
        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
        .disabled(!editMode)
}
```

The parent view handles the `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var context` and `@ObservedObject var todo: Todo`. I would also like to be able to modify it from within the parent view, to change the appearance of the `TextField`, something like (pseudo-code):

```
// pseudo-code
MyEditableTextBlock("Notes", $todo.notes, editMode)
    .font(.title3)
```

and apply the `.font` modifier to the `TextField` (not the .caption header).

What's the "correct" way to do this, and insure that the `item` and `editMode` stay bound to the CoreData context and @State variable in the parent view respectively?

Thanks.

Comment: CoreData autogenerated classes are kind of ObservableObject, so you should use ObservedObject property wrappers to instances of core data objects.

Comment: Sure--but what's the solution to be able to re-use the same bit of code on a different entity, something like `MyEditableTextBloc("Priority", $todo.priority, editMode)` ?